# C-style constants and their values in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constants, c-preprocessor

First of all I am new to IOS app developing, but familiar with C-style languages since I'm from Java-world. I learning to develop for IOS by following this book http://books.google.kz/books/about/Foundation_iPhone_App_Development.html?id=68L0dC2Sl8IC&redir_esc=y . My problems are from Chapter 9.

The first problem is when I try to build, it says "Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type "UIColor" to C pointer type "GCColorRef" (aka 'struct CGColor *') requires a bridged cast". The code is as following (error line is marked with comment):

```
#define kFontLightOnDarkTextColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 255.0/255 green:251.0/255 blue: 218.0/255 alpha:1.0];
#define kFontDarkOnLightTextColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0/255 green:1.0/255 blue:1.0/255 alpha: 1.0];

#define kFontNavigationTextColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 106.f/255.f green:62.f/255.f blue:29.f/255.f alpha: 1.f];
#define kFontNavigationDisabledTextColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 106.f/255.f green: 62.f/255.f blue: 39.f/255.f alpha: 0.6f];
#define kNavigationButtonBackgroundColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 255.f/255.f green: 245.f/255.f blue: 225.f/255.f alpha: 1.f];
#define kToolbarButtonBackgroundColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 39.f/255.f green: 17.f/255.f blue: 5.f/255.f alpha: 1.f];
#define kLargeButtonTextColour [UIColor whiteColor];

#define kFontNavigation [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.f];
#define kFontName [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:30.f];
#define kFontBirthdayDate [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size:13.f];
#define kFontDaysUntilBirthday [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:25.f];
#define kFontDaysUntilBirthdaySubText [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size:9.f];
#define kFontLarge [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.f];
#define kFontButton [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:30.f];
#define kFontNotes [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size:16.f];
#define kFontPicPhoto [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.f];
#define kFontDropShadowColour [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255 green:1.0/255 blue:1.0/255 alpha:0.75];

+(void) styleLabel: (UILabel *)label withType:(TSKLabelType) labelType {
switch(labelType) {
    case TSKLabelTypeName:
        label.font = kFontName;
        label.layer.shadowColor = kFontDropShadowColour.CGColor;//error is here, when I try to use CGColor
        label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
        label.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0f;
        label.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        label.textColor = kFontLightOnDarkTextColour;
        break; }}
```

The second problem's code is below:

```
+(void) initStyles {
NSDictionary* titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: kFontNavigationTextColour, UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 2)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, kFontNavigation, UITextAttributeFont, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleTextAttributes];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];}
```

The line where "titleTextAttributes" is defined says me "Expected ']'", by referring to "kFontNavigation" const. But, that line has no error, instead the line with "kFontNavigationTextColour" says me "Expected ']'".

What are these problems? I am writing and running the same code as it's written in the book. Maybe the problem is in IDE or compiler? My Xcode is 4.5.2 and OS X Lion 10.7.5.

P.S.: all the consttants (define's) and static methods are defined in one class.

Comment: iOS development should be constrained to a permission or a license. One could not get this license until he learned C properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semi colon at the end of the constant definitions:

```
#define kFontNavigationTextColour [UIColor colorWithRed: 106.f/255.f green:62.f/255.f blue:29.f/255.f alpha: 1.f];
```

#define statements don't need a terminating semi colon. If you do add them, the compiler recognizes them as part of the string you are trying to assign to a macro variable.

Comment: Thanks. That solved problem 2. But problem 1 still remains. (when I use CGColor on const object). How to solve that?

Comment: "Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'UIColor *' to C pointer type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'struct CGColor *') requires a bridged cast" error right after "kFontDropShadowColour" const.

Comment: Thanks a lot CrazyIon. I just relaunched the Xcode, the problem is fixed. (What a damned IDE :((). I'll vote you up for help!.